# PHP: Login form with email and password but display first name upon login?

Tags: php, html, forms, function, mysqli

I am new to php coding and the SOF community so please bear with me. I have a functioning sign up system (wired to a database) and somewhat functional login form but how may I be able to make both sessions of the forms display/use the first name of the associated account?

More clarification: Login with email and password, you go to the home page where the system addresses you by your first name. When you sign up, you are directed to another page with the system addressing you by your fist name.

I would assistance on the login part so here are the relevant codes:

Login form (on a header php; separate from my index and registration variables) :

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email_login" size="50" placeholder="Email" /><br /><br /><br />
    <input type="password" name="pass_login" size="50" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="LOG IN">
  </form>
```

Login Code (on index.php with registration form/code and registration variables):

```
if(isset($_POST['email_login']) && isset($_POST['pass_login'])) {

   $email_login = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['email_login']);
   $pass_login = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass_login']);
   $pass_login = md5($pass_login);
  $logquery = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email_login' AND password='$pass_login' LIMIT 1";
  $sqli = mysqli_query($con, $logquery);
  $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqli); // Count number of rows returned

 if ($userCount == 1) {
  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id = $row["id"];
  }

  $_SESSION["email"] = $fname;

  header("location: home.php");

  exit();
}
```

Finally, the home.php; where I want registered users to be directed to upon successful login:

```
<?php session_start();
 include ( "./inc/connect.inc.php");

 echo $_SESSION["email"];
 ?>
```

Sorry if anything is considered as bloat. Thank you.

Comment: did you start the session for all pages using sessions?

Comment: Not on all of the pages, just the pages users are going to be directed to.

Comment: there's the problem then.

Comment: answer(s) should follow........... I'll get back to my Cappuccino. *what are you having Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: *They're on the scene now Sam* @JayBlanchard - Let's just hope they bring in the reinforcements against injection and password takeovers.

Comment: *They're going to ignore the other obvious problems here Ralph.* So far I'm right @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Yes they will be Sam*, so so sad. Let's hope, just hope they'll take you up on it. @JayBlanchard Ok, now my Cappuccino needs tending to. Now THAT, is more pressing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I placed session_start(); on all of the pages using sessions and the echo projects properly, thank you. I accidentally set  $_SESSION["email"] = $fname; instead of $email_login. However, instead of projecting the user's email, I want the user's first name to be projected instead upon logging in with his/her/its email and password; is there a way to do this?

Comment: well, you'll need to take it up with the answers below then. They seemed too quick on the draw, as it were.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you for the advice, I will use it to my advantage. I am unfamiliar with hashing passwords so I will be sure to spend a good amount of time on your links, thank you.

Comment: you need to select something more than just `id` and assign a variable to that session row for the username. you have "answers" below. they should work for it. and / or instruct them that it's wrong and to probably delete it. you should be telling them that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the session using `session_start()` anywhere you want to WRITE or READ session variable.

Simply add `session_start()` at the top of your index.php file.

Also make sure not output has been set before the session starts or you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

First you must start session on the top of every single page (before any other output) where you would read or write session variable adding
this =>`session_start()` and also in your code you set $_SESSION['email'] with a variable ($fname) which was not set (Maybe you forget to retrieve $fname from the the database) You can do it by editing your query

Update

Try this query

`$logquery = "SELECT id, first_name FROM users WHERE email='$email_login' AND password='$pass_login' LIMIT 1";`
Then

```
$sqli = mysqli_query($con, $logquery); $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqli); // Count number of rows returned  
 if ($userCount == 1) { 
     while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
         $id = $row["id"];
         $_SESSION["first_name"] = $row["first_name"];
     }
 } 
header("location: home.php"); exit();
```

Then in your home.php

```
 <?php session_start();
 include ( "./inc/connect.inc.php");
 echo     $_SESSION["first_name"]; ?>
```

Comment: I implemented what you suggested, but the user's email is still projected when the first_name (assuming "username" was your substitute) of the login user should be projected instead. Is there a way, like you mentioned, for me to be able to retrieve the first_name of the user from the database that corresponds to the email/pass they sent through the form? Thanks.

Comment: I made the edits to my $logquery and included the $fname variable(which, like you mentioned, was needed) but the the first_name is not be being retrieved from its corresponding row. Thanks again.

Comment: Which columns name do you have in your database? I mean  id,  email, password etc... Can you list them?

Comment: In order, my columns are: id, email, date_of_birth, password, first_name, last_name, gender, sign_up_date, and activated.

Comment: Try this query   
`$logquery = "SELECT id, first_name FROM users WHERE email='$email_login' AND password='$pass_login' LIMIT 1"`;    
Then 

    $sqli = mysqli_query($con, $logquery);  
    $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqli); // Count number of rows returned

    if ($userCount == 1) {  
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {  
            $id = $row["id"];
            $_SESSION["first_name"] = $row["first_name"];
        }
    }

    header("location: home.php");

    exit();

Comment: Then in your home.php

    <?php session_start();

    include ( "./inc/connect.inc.php");

     echo $_SESSION["first_name"];
     ?>